# windows 7 unattend setupcomplete.cmd

Tags: windows-7, batch, windows-installation, setup, unattended

I have a folder:

```
\sources\$OEM$\$$\Setup\Scripts\Programs\
```

I want to copy this folder contents (couple of files and folders to `C:\Program Files\`) to a system drive using a command in `setupcomplete.cmd`

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%D IN ('dir /a:d /b %~dp0Programs') DO (
    xcopy "%~dp0Programs\%%D\*" "C:\%%D\" /s /i
)
```

for some unknown reason to me this isn't working during unattended windows setup (just a black screen forever), although running `setupcomplete.cmd` from command line works fine.

One problem with `setupcomlete.cmd` during unattended installation is when another .bat or .cmd from another folder (e.g \scripts\folder1) is ran from `setupcomplete.cmd` it will be stuck in that `\scripts\folder1\` thus preventing running further commands from `\scripts\`

I have experimented with `%~dp0` and with some luck, but what works from command line, doesn't work in the real setup situation always.

Comment: Just for completeness ... C:\ isn´t always the system drive. So a better option is using %systemdrive%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In setupcomplete.cmd you can try to implement `cd %~dp0` followed by `cd ..` or `pushd ..`. This should bring you one level higher and you can work with variable path names.

If you just want to copy files/folders, you can put them in `[DVD]:\sources\$OEM$\$1\[*]` where `[*]` is the folder you want to be the destination.

E.g. you want to copy folder `ABC` into `C:\Program Files\` while (or after? I don't know anymore) setup, put folder `ABC` into `[DVD]:\sources\$OEM$\$1\Program Files\`.

`$$` stands for `C:\Windows\`

`$1` stands for `C:\` (drive root)

Comment: `$1` did the trick.thx